# Getting "invalid 'type' (character) of argument" error with aggregate()

Tags: r, aggregate

I have the following CSV:

```
color,val2,val3
blue,1,4
green,7,3
blue,4,2
red,9,3
red,2,6
blue,1,7
```

I simply want to aggregate by color.

When I'm trying:

```
csv <- read.csv("/home/user/file.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data <-aggregate(csv, list(csv[["color"]]), sum)
```

I get

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That error is coming from `sum()`, because you are attempting to sum the character elements in the `color` column.

```
sum("a")
# Error in sum("a") : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

You need to remove the `color` column from the `x` argument, since it is not being used in aggregation, but is actually the `by` argument.

```
aggregate(csv[-1], csv["color"], sum)
#   color val2 val3
# 1  blue    6   13
# 2 green    7    3
# 3   red   11    9
```

But the formula method would also work and is cleaner (but slower).

```
aggregate(. ~ color, csv, sum)
```

Answer (score 5):

In this case, you need to move color to the other side since you really can't aggregate on a character vector. You can also use `dplyr` package as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
csv %>% group_by(color) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

With following output:

```
  color  val2  val3
  (chr) (int) (int)
1  blue     6    13
2 green     7     3
3   red    11     9
```